# "I certainly could" or "I could certainly"

Tags: word-order

Which is better or correct?

> That’s good advice that I certainly could do with heeding.
>
> That’s good advice that I could certainly do with heeding.

Answer (score 0):

"*I certainly could*" is a polite but prudent answer to a "*Could you please...?*" question.

"*I could certainly...*" would require some specification, e.g. "*I could certainly do it, but would it be worth the while?*".

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, definitely, clearly, obviously, probably etc. are adverbs of certainty and are normally used in the mid position. They are used after the auxiliary verbs, after am/is/are/was/were and before verbs.

"That’s good advice that I could certainly do with heeding." is good usage.

Comment: Hello, mahmud. As tchrist has said, we are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.